# Convert pseudo Json string into a Python object

Tags: python, json, encoding, decoding

I have a string that looks like JSON but it's not. I want to convert it into a Python object (back and forth).

Here is the format:

```
v = "{ TestKey = true,
Calibration = 0,
Blacks = 0,
Brightness = 50,
BasicSetting = { 0,
0,
32,
22},
Whites = 0 }"
```

I can not use directly json.load(v) on such string.
What's the best / easiest way to convert it into a Python object ?
Writing a custom Python JSON encoder / decoder ?
I will need to decode the Python back into the original string format.

So far, I'm replacing = by : but I face some issues to correctly put the ' in the original string and I don't think it's the best way to do. Any other suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? SO is not a code factory. If you want our help you have to show some effort.

Comment: So far, pattern substitution but it's kind of a hack, I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: "I will need to decode the Python back into the original string format" -- in this case, you probably want to write a custom json encode/decoder

Comment: This looks sufficiently different from JSON that you won't have much success with any JSON parser, custom or not. In particular, `{0,0,32,22}` appears to be intended as an array, but it starts with the same delimiter as a dictionary and the only way to distinguish it from a dictionary is to look ahead (indefinitely) and see that there's no `= value` part (this is in start contrast to JSON, where you can distinguish arrays and dicts by their starting delimiter). Where is this stupid data format from?

Comment: Some more background would be useful. What will this be used for? Why must it be in this format? Why not use a format for which serializers and deserializers already exist, e.g. JSON or YAML?

Comment: As you say, it's a stupid format, won't comment more on that. Yes, I can replace { by [ and just leave the { for the first and } for the last one... Seems string pattern matching is probably the easiest way to go unless someone suggests an easy way to write a parser ?

Comment: It is ugly but seems to work `import json; import re; v1 = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', r'"\g<1>"', v.replace('=', ':').replace("\n", "")); json.loads(re.sub(r"{([^:]+)}", "[\g<1>]", v1));`

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward to write a small recursive decent parser for this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Thanks zero323 for the regex. However, some keys can have numbers like  Black2013 = 25 so it does not work. I ended-up parsing char by char, with an automaton state to populate a JSON object. It's not very elegant but works. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @user2944669 Actually it is not a problem. I've posted example below. I think I wouldn't use regex myself but I've posted an example below - just for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ugly as hell and some regex ninja would be able to achieve this using half of the symbols but seems to work:

```
import json
import re

def parse(v):
    # Remove newlines and replace "=" with ":"
    v1 =  v.replace('=', ':').replace("\n", "")
    # Enclose strings in double quotes
    v2 = re.sub(r'(\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)', r'"\g<1>"', v1)
    # If you want booleans
    v3 = re.sub(r'"(true|false)"', r'\g<1>', v2)
    # Create lists
    return json.loads(re.sub(r"{([^:]+)}", r'[\g<1>]', v3))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have still kept my automaton because the value could also have some " like "here is my text" so I ended-up with some issues with the regexp. Thanks again for having taken time to provide a solution.